# Incrementally reconstruct a high-resolution image from a sequence of low-resolution images

Tags: image-processing, compression, fft, image-compression

I have a high resolution image that I need to transmit over low-bandwidth, lossy comms. I need to break the high-resolution image down into a sequence of *much* lower resolution images (of order 64 bytes). I want to transmit these low resolution images one at a time, and *incrementally* reconstruct a higher-resolution image (so I want to minimise redundancy between the low-resolution images).

I sense a Fourier transform in my future.

my daily driver is Python, in case there's an existing solution to this problem.

Comment: try asking this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ and research https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Video_Coding and video encoding in general. please review [ask]. this post shows very little research.

Comment: JPEG, PNG and other file formats already offer an interlaced option for incremental rendering. Slow communication is how the internet started out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo for my domain i have access to 32-64 byte packets, several minutes apart, with packet loss as high as 75%. Ie. *very* constrained.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I appreciate the feedback. As you've identified, I don't know enough about the solution to this problem to frame the question particularly well. Thank you for the resources you've linked there.

Comment: if this is for rocket science, perhaps you should say that. -- you don't have to "frame it well". a keyhole is a kind of frame too. don't make us peep through a keyhole. give us a panoramic view. -- academics have a penchant for talking abstractly (vaguely). lose that. your problem here is engineering. -- if you wanna be mathematic about this, start talking about information theory, channel capacity, coding, shannon et al... then you'll have some idea what kinda research you are looking for.